# Rear wheel deflating instantly after pumping

Tags: mountain-bike, tire, wheels, puncture

I have a mountain bike and recently the rear wheel has gone flat and every time i pump air into it up to 50 psi it deflates after a few minutes
I also hear air coming out a certain part of the wheel but i'm not sure what to do since this is my first time that I have gotten a flat wheel

Edit: I took apart the wheel and found a tiny hole in the tube, should i replace the tube or patch it?

Answer (score 4):

Find what caused the hole and fix the issue. Remove the thorn or glass, etc.
Check [this answer for how to find the flat cause](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/8073/fixing-a-flat-how-to-find-the-piercing-object).

Patching is cheaper but requires a little skill.
New tube is easier and more expensive.
Check [this answer for how to fix a puncture.](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52/how-do-i-fix-a-puncture)

Flats are part of owning a bike. Fixing a flat is a key skill.
There are right ways and wrong ways of putting a tube in a tire.
Sheldon Brown has a complete write up on [tires, flats, and installation.](https://sheldonbrown.com/flats.html)